# Difference between x and p in gdb?

Tags: debugging, unix, gdb

I'm a bit confused about the uses of x and p in gdb. Which one do I use to look at the contents of a register and which one to look at something in memory?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`x` shows you the contents of a memory address

`p` shows you the value stored in a named variable

`info registers` and `info frame` shows you registers and what they're doing.

Comment: What about something like print $al versus x/x $al ? I believe they all will output the same thing. $al isn't really a memory address and it's not a user defined variable.