# Change Code Flow

Tags: c

I am trying to change the flow of this program. I want it to call the win function. This is not the exact code but this will explain what the code does.

```
void win() {
    printf("Code Flow Changed\n");
}

int main() {
    char input[10];
    scanf("%10s",input);
    void (*function)() = (void (*)())input;
    function();
    return 0;
}
```

The address of win function is 0x0a245101.

When I tried to change it,every time I end up changing p/x $eax value instead of x $eax. Can anyone explain what does x $eax and p/x $eax show.

```
(gdb) x $eax
0xf7ffb000: 0x0a245101
(gdb) p/x $eax
$2 = 0xf7ffb000
```

Edit: Also please explain what does this mean.

```
void (*function)() = (void (*)())input;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`p/x $eax` shows you the value that is currently in the `eax`.

`x $eax` shows you not only the value that is currently in the `eax`, but also the value in the address of `eax`'s value.

Sorry, my English is bad, I hope you can understand...

Actually, it may have a better answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21058681/difference-between-x-and-p-in-gdb)

`void (*function)()` stands for a function pointer, which can point to a function which takes no parameter and returns void.

`(void (*)())input` means to convert `input` to a function which takes no parameter and returns void.

And `void (*function)() = (void (*)())input;` means use the function pointer to point at the address of `input`, why? Because you tell compiler that `input` has been converted to a function.

Answer (score 0):

Address is an integer value, not a char array. You should do the following:

```
void win() {
    printf("Code Flow Changed\n");
}

int main() {
    void *input = 0;
    printf("%p\n", win); // print the address of win
    scanf("%p",&input);  // re-type the address of win
    void (*function)() = (void (*)())input;
    function();
    return 0;
}
```

Output on my machine:

```
0x109d24ef0
0x109d24ef0
Code Flow Changed
```

Comment: I am giving the input through a python command not through stdin.